# tomcat: loading swf into page

Tags: java, flash, tomcat6

what's the recommended method to load an SWF file in my page ?

just to use HttpServletResponse.getWriter and to print with it the SWF object, or is there a more efficient method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a static SWF file, simply place it in a publicly browsable path and allow Tomcat to serve it as a static file. If you are generating an SWF file dynamically, [`ServletResponse.getWriter()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter()) is perfectly fine as long as you remember to set the `Content-type` HTTP header to `application/x-shockwave-flash`. You can do that just before writing to the output stream with [`ServletResponse.setContentType()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)) like this:

```
resp.setContentType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
```

You may also want to think about setting some HTTP caching related headers such as `Cache-Control` and `Expires` if you want browsers to be able to cache your SWF files. You can do that with [`HttpServletResponse.setHeader()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or [`HttpServletResponse.addHeader()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). For the case of a static SWF file, you will have to set caching headers in a [`Filter`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/Filter.html) mapped with a `<url-pattern>`.

Another point worth mentioning is that referencing SWF content in a cross browser friendly way that bypasses an irritating [extra-click behavior in some versions of MSIE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb969055.aspx) has become some kind of black magic. I recommend using the [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) library (hosted on Google Code) to abstract the ugliness away.